# Is it possible to merge two python data frames with different columns into a json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have two df that do not have the same columns. I want a .json file with one df as a subcategory of the other. Here are the data frames:

```
category = pd.DataFrame({
  'Day': ['day1', 'day1', 'day2', 'day2'],
  'Type': ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2'],
  'school': ['harvard', 'columbia', 'yale', 'ucla'],
  'maxage': ['30', '40', '50', '60'],
  'minage': ['20', '31', '41', '51']
})

subcategory = pd.DataFrame({
  'Day': ['day1', 'day1', 'day1', 'day2', 'day2'],
  'studenttype': ['top', 'advanced', 'average', 'average', 'top'],
  'maxage': [29, 24, 37, 54, 51],
  'minage': [27, 20, 32, 58, 52]
})
```

I want the day to match and the max-min age (for example 29-27) in 'subcategory' to be within the max-min age (for example 30-20) in 'category'. The json file should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "Day": "day1",
    "category": [
      {
        "school": "harvard",
        "Type": "Type1",
        "maxage": 30,
        "minage": 20,
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "studenttype": "top",
            "maxage": 29,
            "minage": 27
          },
          {

            "studenttype": "advanced",
            "maxage": 24,
            "minage": 20
          } 
        ]
      }
     ]
    "category": [
      {
        "school": "columbia",
        "Type": "Type1",
        "maxage": 40,
        "minage": 31,
        "subcategory": [
           {
             "studenttype": "average",
             "maxage": 37,
             "minage": 32
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
  {
    "Day": "day2",
    "category": [
       {"school": "ucla",
        "Type": "type2",
        "maxage": 60,
        "minage": 51,
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "studenttype": "average",
            "maxage": 58,
            "minage": 54
          },
         {
            "studenttype": "top",
            "maxage": 52,
            "minage": 51
          }
         ]
       }
     ]
    }
  ]
```

I haven't used json files before and I'm new to python so I'm wondering how to approach the problem. Should I start by merging the two data frames and fill empty spaces with NaN values or does that just complicate things?

Comment: your desired outcome is not a valid dictionary

Comment: do you mean that I made a mistake in the outcome (I made it manually to show how it should look like)? or is it not possible to get something like this?

Comment: I meant, when I try to run this, I get errors.